# Are all topological (finite-dim) real vector spaces homeomorphic to a coordinate space?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, gn.general-topology, linear-algebra

I know that all real, finite-dimensional topological vector spaces are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, but are they also homeomorphic?

The reason I'm asking this is because I was wondering whether or not there were any disconnected real topological vector spaces.

Comment: Since sum and scalar product have to be continuous, I guess that the space is in fact path connected, because of $\lambda\mapsto \lambda V+(1-\lambda)W$ is a path connecting any $V$ and $W\in V$.   

Comment: Your isomorphism also gives you a homeomorphism

Comment: If you insist that the vector space topology is Hausdorff (otherwise take a seminorm which is not a norm) then it is true that the dimension determines the homeomorphism type, but it is *not* trivial. It is easier if you require in addition local convexity. André Weil proves the general fact in one of the very first sections of his "Basic Number Theory".

Comment: @Theo: Does he do it using uniform spaces (which were his invention, if I remember correctly)?

Comment: A strange question because, as remarked, isomorphism of TVS are in particular homeomorphism. Maybe you meant: if a real TVS is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as top. space), is it also isomorphic to it as TVS ? Yes, because a Hausdorff real TVS is finite dimensional iff is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, iff it is locally compact; not trivial but not even difficult fact that you can find in any book on the subject. 

Comment: @Pietro: I took that "isomorphic" means "as a linear space". I agree that it is not *that* difficult (essentially it boils down to compactness of the unit ball in standard $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). @Harry: No, uniform structures do not enter explicitly (but they lurk around, of course). Yes, uniform structures were invented by Weil, they arose in his investigations of topological groups in the late 30's.

Comment: Another reference besides Weil's book is Alain Robert's A First Course in p-Adic Analysis, Appendix A.6 to Chapter II.  His argument, like Weil's, uses Haar measure.  It proceeds by induction on the dimension.

Comment: As the Theo B said, if you do not insist that your vector spaces be Hausdorff, then the answer is trivially no: your favorite vector space with the indiscrete topology is such that all operations (addition, negation, multiplication) are continuous, but it is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Theo J: That makes sense. 

Comment: In fact true for any complete field in place of $\mathbb R$ ... even if not locally compact.


Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any (Hausdorff) topological real vector space of dimension $n<\infty$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^n$ with the standard topology, see e.g. Rudin, Functional analysis, theorem 1.21.

Here are some comments:

1. For some reason it is stated there for complex vector spaces, but, as remarked after the theorem, the proof works for real vector spaces as well.
2. Instead of the Hausdorff axiom Rudin uses the (weaker) $T_1$ axiom in the definition of a topological vector space.

Comment: If a toplogical group is $T_1$ then since {e} is a closed set and 
$f : (x,y) \mapsto xy^{-1}$ is continuous, the diagonal, in $G$ which is $f^{-1}(e)$ is closed, i.e., $G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Dick -- that's a nice proof! Rudin does prove that as well, but his proof is a bit longer and more technical.

Comment: In fact, you only need $T_{0}$ to conclude that a topological group is Hausdorff: If $U$ contains $x$ but not $y$ then $yx^{-1}U$ contains $y$ but not $x$, so a $T_{0}$ group is $T_{1}$. Now Use Dick's argument.